# Pari/Gp directing output

Tags: output, pari

Is there an easy convenient way to direct output in Pari/GP to file? My aim is to get the full decimal expansion of `2^400000-1` either on screen or in a text file?

```
(23:37) gp > 2^400000-1
%947 = 996014342993......(4438 digits)......609762267975[+++]
```

GP terminal output gives this, which is not the goal. Basic output re-direction does not work either. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
(23:38) gp > 2^400000-1 > output.txt
```

There is a manual online, it does not say much about the output, except for the variable TeXstyle. I am unsure how to work with this though.

Comment: Please, use `\w` metacommand to write out. E.g., just `\w /path/to/output.txt` to print the last result to some file path/to/output.txt.

Answer (score 1):

Quick and easy is to just do `print(2^400000-1)` and then you can cut+paste. Otherwise `write(filename, 2^400000-1)` if you want in a file.

Answer (score 1):

Some other possibilities:

1. `writebin(filename,2^400000-1)` writes the object binary structure in a file: this is faster than traditional output (which implies a binary to decimal conversion), and loading it into another session will be faster as well. This is useful for a huge atomic write.
2. C-style output: `fileopen`, then successive `filewrite` allows many writes to a file referenced by a descriptor (which avoids re-opening / flushing / closing the file after each write). This is useful for a large write operation done through many tiny writes to a given file, e.g, character by character.